# decoding failed, system halted during legacy boot (possibly due to large SATA drive attached)

Tags: linux, boot, bios, initrd

I booted liveUSB stick based on Linux Mint 20.2. After outputting initrd line (one after vmlinuz) I got empty screen with "decoding failed, system halted" (tried twice,  error got reproduced). That happened in 1 of 4 cases only: legacy boot with large (>4TB) SATA drive attached; UEFI booted with drive (one 4Tb and one >4TB) and legacy booted w/out that drive (only one 4TB attached) (4th: UEFI w/out disk I have not tried). Web search for support of large drives found: https://superuser.com/questions/1005475/trying-to-understand-linux-support-for-4tb-hard-disk-drive-on-legacy-bios where:

> All that said, since the new disk is a non-boot disk, you needn't
> really be concerned with these issues.

For "decoding failed, system halted" I've read a number of found links: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269855/usb-installer-initramfs-unpacking-failed-decoding-failed, https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=328925, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1870260, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355231/decoding-failed-system-halted, https://www.quora.com/Now-I-am-booting-Ubuntu-20-10-with-flash-card-When-booting-it-is-saying-Decoding-failed-system-halted-What-should-I-do, https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/q7ahdx/decoding_failed_system_halted_problem/.

I do not see how it applies to my issue, they talk about bugs in initrd for compression, drive failing on hardware level, randomly occurring issue. My guess it that somehow in BIOS/legacy mode initrd cannot identify large SATA disk. How can I check that?

Added 1:
Another issue today:

```
64 bit relocation outside of kernel! 
--- system halted
```

again after `loading initrd.lz...` output supports PSU failing hypothesis of the answer. System booted with no power to harddrives, when I connected one - boom that new one.

Comment: The quora post suggests checking that you've correctly downloaded the live installation. I'd try that again from scratch, checksum the result and then install that to your usb

Comment: @roaima, why doesn't it "like" that particular harddrive during boot? Or maybe sata cable (as I have not tried to put another drive on that cable) or...

Comment: Does your USB boot without the external drive attached? That's not clear from your question

Comment: The answer I think gets it right, I was able to boot with those two drives attached later, so that effect of that particular drive in the question looks like a *glitch* due to power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Decoding failed, system halted" seems to imply that the initramfs decompression routine detected an error. If that is true, then the error happened very early in the boot process, before the kernel even attempts to detect any SATA controllers.

If initramfs was successfully unpacked, the system would drop into initramfs-based emergency mode on SATA access error instead of halting.

Instead, you should check for causes like this:

- a poorly plugged-in SATA connector or a bad cable might cause data errors that come and go as you move cables around when disconnecting/re-connecting disks. (But that should not affect booting from a live USB...)
- a power supply that's old and starting to fail might no longer be up to the task of spinning up all the disks simultaneously (so disconnecting any disk may help as it reduces the load). The RAM memory or the USB stick might get a slight undervoltage at boot time, just enough to cause data corruption on reading the initramfs file but unfortunately not enough to trigger undervoltage detection.
- a fault in the "disliked" HDD might cause it to draw an abnormal amount of current at start-up, causing an undervoltage event to the rest of the system, resulting in data corruption reading the USB stick.

Comment: Thank you. I have not thought that power supply and hdd may cause current variations for USB. That PC is old and I see glitches/freezes often, so it is in such case a likely cause.